# Using UISegmentedControl set the default is the first time does not display the data

Tags: swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqvsf.png)

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
       segmentedControl =   UISegmentedControl(items: ["Show Html","Show DF","LoadData about PDF"])
       segmentedControl.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 30)
      webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 60, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
    self.view.addSubview(segmentedControl)
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
}

func ValueChanged(sender:UISegmentedControl)
{
    let index = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
    switch index
    {
    case 0:webView.loadHTMLString("<h1><a href = 'http://www.baidu.com'>这是测试LoadHtml</a></h1>", baseURL: nil)
    case 1:
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Stm32", ofType: "pdf")!

        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
        print(url)
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
    case 2:
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Stm32", ofType: "pdf")
        let url  = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
        webView.loadData(data!, MIMEType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL:url)
    default: print("Unknown")
    }
}
```

When I want to use UISegmentedControl to switch to different UIWebView load data mode, the default choice UISegmentedControl index of the first, but does not show data, do not know what is the reason. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call *ValueChanged()* in your last line of *viewDidLoad* or call *webView.loadHTMLString(...)*
    . When you call selectedSegmentIndex does not mean automatically call ValueChanged

Comment: Thanks for your help, I edit my code and add ValueChanged(segmentedControl) this invoke  in my viewDidLoad() method. Now can directly display the data after the start.

Answer (score 0):

Two things: 1. as of iOS 5, the `value changed` event is not fired when you programmatically set `selectedSegmentIndex` and 2. you need to "wire up" the control to your handler function. Add the following line to `viewDidLoad` after you create the `UISegmentedControl`

```
segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: "ValueChanged:", forControlEvents:.ValueChanged)
```

Comment: I remember, I have to join addTarget several times before the test, but also will not display the data